# how to send NMI to Guest OS on ESXi 6.0 via VCenter server?

Tags: vmware, esxi, vcenter

We can send NMI to Guest OS via Vcenter Server Using "All vCenter Actions"->"Export Diagnostic Data."->"HungVM"->"Send_NMI_To_Guest" option.
[image: Send_NMI_To_Guest]

It works well in ESXi 6.5, ESXi 6.7 host.
but if it is ESXi 6.0, the NMI is not sent to Guest OS, and the generated log bundle contains vmx file only.

the ESXi 6.0 host is include patch 2145956(https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2145956?lang=en_US)

is send NMI to ESXi 6.0 is disabled? 
how to fix it?

thanks.

Comment: That should work, so I would suggest opening a support ticket with VMware.

Comment: @KyleRuddy, thanks your reply,
It's my fault for patched the 2145956 patch only, not included the 2120539.
after re-apply related patch, it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my fault for not patched ESXi host fully.
the patch for Send NMI to VM(2145956) on HP Proliant Gen 9 server ESXi server host have bug and after patch it fails to detect local disk, and can't send NMI to VM guest.
after  re-apply ESXi600-201504001, ESXi600-201505001 and ESXi600-201602001 patch, send NMI to Guest OS works well.

> This issue occurs because the existing scsi-hpsa driver that was included in the HP custom image was replaced by the scsi-hpsa driver that are included in the ESXi 6.0 patches and Update 1.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2120539